# Error while trying to display images in Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am building an app which will list a bunch of celebrities in a table view. It will include their image and their Twitter username. I am getting no errors in the editor, however when I run my app, I get the following message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm not sure as to why I am getting this message and what I can do to fix it...

Here is the code from my ViewController:

```
class CelebListViewController: UITableViewController {

    let celebs = Celeb.celebsFromBundle()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return celebs.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: CelebListViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CelebListViewCell

        //Keep
        let celeb = celebs[indexPath.row]

        cell.setCell(celeb.twitter, imageName: celeb.imageName)

        return cell

    }

}
```

And here is the code from my ViewCell:

```
class CelebListViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var handle: UILabel!

    func setCell(handleText: String, imageName: String) {
        self.handle.text = handleText
        self.pic.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }

}
```

I feel like this problem is caused by me using UIImage instead of UIImageView somewhere but I cannot find it.

Anyways, thanks for the help.

P.S. I have a celebrity object where I am setting up all the data. Here is the code for that just in case:

```
struct Celeb {
    let name: String
    let twitter: String
    let imageName: String
    let image: UIImage

    init(name: String, twitter: String, image: UIImage, imageName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.twitter = twitter
        self.image = image
        self.imageName = imageName
    }

    static func celebsFromBundle() -> [Celeb] {

        var celebs = [Celeb]()

        guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("celebs", ofType: "json"),
            data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) else {
                return celebs
        }

        do {
            let rootObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

            guard let celebObjects = rootObject["celebs"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                return celebs
            }

            for celebObject in celebObjects {
                if let name = celebObject["name"] as? String,
                    twitter = celebObject["twitter"]  as? String,
                    imageName = celebObject["image"] as? String,
                    image = UIImage(named: imageName) {

                    let celeb = Celeb(name: name, twitter: twitter, image: image, imageName: imageName)
                    celebs.append(celeb)

                }
            }

        } catch {
            return celebs
        }

        return celebs
    }

}
```

Also here is my Storyboard document outline if that helps:
[image]

Image connections:
[image]

Comment: Check the interface builder, make sure there arent any unused/duplicate connections.

Comment: No I don't think I have any...I've added a screenshot of my storyboard document outline in my original question if you want to take a look

Comment: No, a connection is when you drag to the code to make an outlet.

Comment: Right click on your image view and show me that image

Comment: Sure, check edited post

Comment: I posted the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the problem. You have two outlet connections, image and pic. Delete "image" because in your code you are using "pic".
Xcode gets confused when you have multiple connections.
Hope it helps!

P.S. To delete the "image" connection, simply hit the "X" button next to it.